# React multiple language app - How to render large content with react router based on selected language?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, internationalization, i18next

I have a website in 2 languages. I am using i18n for translations but for large contents such as privacy policy etc. I want to have 2 files/or components in each language.For routing I am using react router.
I see that it seems common to have routes for different languages.

```
const baseUrl = () => (i18n.language === "de" ? "/" : "/" + i18n.language);
```

I wonder if it is the common way for large content to then just render different components in the needed language? How would I do it?

```
<Router basename={baseUrl()}>
      <div className="App">
         <Header />
         <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
            <Route path='terms' element={<Terms />} />
            <Route path='privacy' element={<Privacy />} />
         </Routes>
         <Footer />
     </div>
</Router>
```

or can I use conditionals as:

```
 <Route path='terms' element={i18n.language === 'en' ? <TermsEN/>: <TermsDE />} />
```

thanks!